# Regex to remove a character if followed by another character in java

Tags: java, regex

Working on a regex in java to find words that follow the below rules

Regex Rules:

1. Word could start with - (**optional** Prefix)letters could be any of these 'c''p''y''r''a''u'
2. Followed by capital T
3. Followed by number between 0 to 9
4. (**optional** Suffix)Followed by lower case letters that doesn't include
   letters p or y or r or u. Can be one or two letters

Problem:If the above said suffix for the word is a or b or c and followed by a capital N then the regex should ignore that letter and what follows it.Look in test cases for clarification.

Test cases

1. pT1c - should return the whole word pT1c (since N doesnt follow the c)
2. cT4bcN2 - should return just cT4b (since c is followed by N ignore those two letters and the rest that follows them)
3. cT3cN2 - should return cT3(since c is followed by N ignore those 2 letters and the rest that follows them)

So far I have

> [cpyrau]*[T][0-9X?][a-oqstv-z]{0,2}([N])?(?(1)(?=[abc]))

Which works for the first test case but for all others it includes the letter before N if it is a or c so I’m getting cT4bc and cT3c for second and third test case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a place where to ask for exercise. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: It is not an exercise.I gave the solution I tried in the question too.I'm just asking for help with why it includes the letter c with it.

Comment: @Ferie Of course it is.  The OP explained the requirement and showed their attempt.

Comment: So the 2 at the end of the test cases is not permitted either since according to (4) it must only be lower case letters excluding `pryu`.  You should show some other more complex test cases and their expected result.

Comment: Yes.Anything that follows a/b/cN should be discarded too

Comment: What about `cT4bc2`?

Comment: T(number) can only be followed by 1 or 2 letters and then N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/AIgdb9/3) do what you are after?

```
\b[cpyrau]*T\d(?:(?![a-c]N)[a-oqstv-z]){0,2}
```